# C# Mouse Hover Event for Background Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, panel, mousehover

I am making a Windows Form and I am having trouble getting a Mouse Hover Event to work the way I want to. I have 50 little panels grouped together inside 1 big panel. I want to make info popup whenever the user hovers over a little panel.

Rather than making a mouse hover event for each little panel, I am trying to make just one mouse hover event for the big panel. Whenever the user hovers their mouse in anywhere inside the big panel, my code will determine whether or not they are hovering inside a little panel and if they are it will identify the little panel and display the pertinent info.

However, I am finding that the big panel mouse hover event does not trigger if I hover over a little panel since it is technically in the little panel boundaries and outside of the big panel boundaries (sort of like how Lesotho is it's own country even though it is inside South Africa's borders).

Is there some sort of way around this?

[image]

Comment: You could try assigning the same event handler to all panels and cast the sender `(object sender, EventArgs e)` to determine which panel is triggering the event

Comment: Indeed the big panel won't trigger when the mouse is over a small one. The form also won't receive mouse events.. - Create the (one!) event along with the panels when you create them dynamically, as I hope you do!!

Answer (score 2):

Cleanest solution would be to implement your own `LittlePanel` control:

```
public class LittlePanel : Panel
{
    public class HoverEventArgs
    {
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public HoverEventArgs(bool active)
        {
            Active = active;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<HoverEventArgs> Hover;

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        OnHover(true);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        OnHover(false);
    }

    protected void OnHover(bool active)
    {
        EventHandler<HoverEventArgs> hover = Hover;
        if (hover != null) hover(this, new HoverEventArgs(active));
    }
}
```

Then subscribe to the `Hover` events raised by all `LittlePanels` within the "big" `Panel`:

```
foreach (Control control in bigPanel.Controls)
{
    if (control is LittlePanel)
    {
        ((LittlePanel)control).Hover += littlePanel_Hover;
    }
}
```

Using a shared event handler:

```
void littlePanel_Hover(object sender, LittlePanel.HoverEventArgs e)
{
    // Your code goes here...
}
```

You might also consider adding shared functionality to the `LittlePanel` control, such as contained labels, *etc*.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with what S. Brentson suggested. I made my own custom event handler called `GridMouseHover` in my `Form.cs` file.

```
    private void GridMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I then linked the `MouseHover` event of each of my controls to my new `GridMouseHover` event during my `Form_Load` event so that they will all be linked before a `MouseHover` event could possibly trigger.

```
    private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.panel1.MouseHover += GridMouseHover;
        this.panel2.MouseHover += GridMouseHover;
        this.panel3.MouseHover += GridMouseHover;
        //etc...
    }
```

I had already created all of my panels by hand in my `Form.cs[Design]` window which is why I did not try TaW's suggestion, but I will definitely try that next time since making everything by hand was very tedious. Thanks for the help!

Comment: When you next find yourself designing such a form it becomes worth your while to add the panels at run-time. It's much easier and you'd be done writing your code in less than 5 minutes rather than taking ages doing it in the designer.

Comment: Something else you might consider in the future is to is to create a user control containing all the labels and stuff you have for your panels. In the code of the user control you could allow the necessary info to be passed to it and handle the mouse over in there. From there on you just drag and drop the control onto your form without the need for assigning event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

try this on your single event e.g hope this will help you

```
private void Panaal_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   Control ctr = sender as Control;
   if (ctr.Name.Equals("Panel Name"))
    {
     //your POP Up code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the top control to be transparent to Mouse Events you can use this code:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
    const int HTTRANSPARENT = -1;

    switch(m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_NCHITTEST:
            m.Result = (IntPtr)HTTRANSPARENT;
            break;
        default:
            base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

By example, you have an image and there is a button behind it that can pass the mouse over and the button will execute the MouseHover event.